# How to update array field in subdocumented schema structure in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, rest

TaskInfo Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var taskInfo = mongoose.Schema({

     isactive:{type:Boolean}, 
     taskobject:{type:String}, 
     taskdetails:{type:String}, 
     iscompleted:{type:Boolean}

    });


    var TaskInfo = mongoose.model('TaskInfo', taskInfo);
    module.exports.TaskInfo = TaskInfo;
    module.exports.TaskInfoSchema = taskInfo;
```

TaskSchema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TaskInfoSchema = require("./taskinfo.js").TaskInfoSchema

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Task schema
var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({

 tasktype  : {type: String},
 createdon : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 //createdby : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'},
 //visitedby : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}],
 taskinfo  : [TaskInfoSchema]  

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

Here is routefile/ controller:

```
var TaskInfo = require('../models/taskinfo.js').TaskInfo;
var Task = require('../models/task.js');
var config = require('../../config');
module.exports = function (app, express) {

    var api = express.Router();

    //GET method is for fetching all the tasks from the database,
    api.get('/taskdb', function (req, res) {

        //console.log("____");

        Task.find({}, function (err, taskdb) {

            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(taskdb);
        });
    });


    //POST method is for saving all the tasks to the database,
    api.post('/tasks', function (req, res) {

        var task = {};
        task.tasktype = req.body.tasktype;

        task.taskinfo = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < req.body.taskInfo.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var taskInfo = new TaskInfo(req.body.taskInfo[i]);
            task.taskinfo.push(taskInfo);
        }

        var taskObj = new Task(task);

        taskObj.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Task has been created'
            })

        });
    });


    return api
}
```

I am trying to add REST api to update the values by everytime facing error, someone please tell me how arrays are updated, please suggest me some good resource if you find it is too much basic and shouldnot be asked here.

Here is my code for update operation:

```
api.use('/tasks/:taskId',function(req, res, next){

      Task.findById(req.params.taskId, function(err, task){

        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
               }
        else if(task)
        {
          req.task = task;
          next();
        }
        else
        {
        res.status(404).send ('no task found with such details');
        }
        });
    });


api.patch ('/tasks/:taskId',function(req,res){
  if(req.body._id)
    delete req.body._id;

  for(var p in req.body)
      {
        req.tasktype[p] = req.body[p];
      }
  for(var p in req.body)
      {
        req.taskInfo[p] = req.body[p];
      }

  req.taskobj.save(function(err){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
        }
       res.json({message:'Task edited & updated '})

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update document using $set operator

1) If you want to update subdocument on basis of subdocument id

```
var id = taskInfoId;

here i  am going to update field "isactive" of particular taskinfo

    Task.update({"taskinfo._id":id},{$set:{"isactive":true}},function(err,success){
    if(err){
    }else{

    }
    });
```

2) if you want to update subdocument on basis of parent document id,then

```
var taskId = taskId;

   Task.update({"_id":taskId},{$set:{"isactive":true}},function(err,success){
    if(err){
    }else{

    }
    });
```

Comment: Can you write code for same like you did for POST api ? I am not able to implement it correctly.

Comment: i have changed code ._id="False" so subdocumented schema dont have id field, can you please tell me for any field of taskinfo array instead of just single field, if any field need update

Comment: what you mean by that,i don't understand,do you want to update whole task info array ?

Comment: sir i want to update any field which are inside taskinfo array... like iscompleted or taskdetails... in a way we take response from user which field he want to edit and do update in database

Comment: sir but i already said in am not using id field in subdocument, i am preferring 2nd option and even for that we are doing set for isactive field what if user want to set some other field on a random element of array, how would be know at what position in array we need to modify